# Getting Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name Error using Spring Boot 2

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 2 to create web application and running the application using CommandLineRunner to connect PostgreSql database

**1 . "LinkRepository" Interface:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.entity.Link;

public interface LinkRepository extends CrudRepository<Link, Long> {

}
```

**2. 'Link' Entity :**

```
    package com.example.entity;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "link")
    public class Link {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "url", unique = true)
        private String url;

        public Link(String name, String url) {
            this.name = name;
            this.url = url;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

    }
```

**3. Demo Application Config:**

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

    import com.example.entity.Link;

    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.example" })
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        public CommandLineRunner demo(LinkRepository repository) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            return (args) -> {
                repository.save(new Link("test", "link"));
                for (Link linkrepo : repository.findAll()) {
                    System.out.println(linkrepo.getName());

                }
            };
        }
    }
```

**4. Pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

**5. Application.properties :**

```
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDb
  spring.datasource.username=postgres
  spring.datasource.password=root
  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
  spring.h2.console.enabled=true
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
  spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
  spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

**I am getting following error :**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in com.example.demo.DemoApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'demo' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'linkRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.entity.Link

Comment: Did you try to move the Link entity in the `com.example.demo` package (i.e. into `com.example.demo.entity` package? Maybe `scanBasePackages` is not working as you expected. I also always annotate the Repository with `@Repository`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@EntityScan("com.example.entity")` on DemoApplication class or move DemoApplication to 'com.example' package and then spring will scan all sub-packages.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CommandLineRunner, then that should be something like this:

```
`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.example" })
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
       return (args) -> {
       repository.save(new Link("test", "link"));
       for (Link linkrepo : repository.findAll()) {
           System.out.println(linkrepo.getName());
       }
    };
}
```

I've just prefer doing that like this:

1) Create a new class called for example DemoBootstrap
2) And it should be soemthing like this

```
@Component
public class DemoBootstrap implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

private final LinkRepository categoryRepository;

public DemoBootstrap(LinkRepository linkRepository) {
    this.linkRepository = linkRepository;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    // Here add all links that should be saved
    // for example
    linkRepository.save(new Link("foo", "bar"));
    linkRepository.save(new Link("foo2", "bar2"));

    // etc

}
```